# Class inheritance issue

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to implement an AVL tree. Initially I implemented two classes, node and node_AVL as such:

```
class node{
protected:
    int info;
    node *l, *r;
public:
    node *getRight();
};

class node_AVL : public node{
protected:
    int height;
public:
    void setHeight(int):
};
```

The problem arises when for example I try to access the child of a node:

```
node_AVL *node1 = node2.getRight();
```

Or

```
node_AVL node;
node.getRight().setHeight(1);
```

I get these errors:

Invalid conversion from node* to node_AVL*

Class node has no member setHeight()

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "problem arises"? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: Please make a [MRE] for example what is `getRight`? Assuming `getRight` returns a `node*` the line `node_AVL node1 = node2.getRight();` can't work, because 1.) you try to assign a pointer to a non-pointer-variable and 2.) you can't assign a `node *` to a `node_AVL *`, because a `node *` is not necessarily a `node_AVL *`.

Comment: `node2.getRight()` presumably returns a `node*`, which may or may not point at a `node_AVL*`, so you're not allowed to call those methods.

Comment: I think I get it now, but is there a way to create a class that inherits node but adds new data, like height in my example?

Comment: Your example does exactly that, it creates "a class that inherits node but adds new data". That happens to be exactly what it does.

Comment: You've run into what the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle) warns of. You have a hierarchy that makes sense on the surface, but doesn't make sense the way you need to use it.

Comment: Note: your `node` needs to have a public virtual destructor if its subclasses can ever be deleted through a `node` pointer. Otherwise, all their fields leak on `~node()` call , e.g. node_AVL::height (it probably can even cause undefined behavior). If objects of derived classes mustn't be deleted through a pointer to the superclass, you can explicitly forbid it by making `~node()` protected.

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages say, this line:

```
node_AVL *node1 = node2.getRight();
```

doesn't work because `getRight()` returns a `node*`. You could fix this by making `node1` a `node*`, like this:

```
node *node1 = node2.getRight();
```

For the second part, you would need to do something like:

```
node node;
node.getRight()->setHeight(1);
```

This wouldn't work either since `setHeight` is a member of `node_AVL`.

You should maybe redesign your class, bearing in mind what you're trying to accomplish.